# Multiple responses for the same code using custom annotations

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Using Spring to implement a REST API. Some endpoints will support CSV, other will not. I want to avoid having CSV as a response in all endpoints like this:

```
@ApiResponses(
    @ApiResponse(description = "OK", responseCode = "200", content = {
        @Content(mediaType = JSON, schema = @Schema(…),
        @Content(mediaType = CSV, schema = @Schema(…)
    }
)
```

I want to hava a custom annotation, @EnableCSV for example, that will add that response type to the endpoint without having to write it every time. If I create a meta-annotation with @ApiResponse, response for 200 gets overridden (you can only specify one @ApiResponse for each responseCode unless it's grouped like that). Any other way to do this? Can I group both in an annotation and maybe just replace the @Schema for the first one by a parameter? Kinda like @EnableCSV(schema = @Schema(...)) that will only put that schema for the regular 200 and keep the CSV one too.

Using swagger v3

Thanks.